# Organize Iris Data in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, list-comprehension

given the following information:

http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/iris/iris.data

i need to have an output that:

1. Sepal length 2. Sepal width 3. Petal length 4. Petal width 5. Class: a. Iris Setosa b. Iris Versicolour c. Iris Virginica

The code needs to have an output file named iris-summary.txt.

The output file should give the average values of the sepal and petal lengths and widths. A suggested output format is:
average sepal length, average sepal width, average petal length, average petal width, Class
In this case the correct output will be formatted as:
6.588, 2.974, 5.552, 2.026, Iris-virginica
5.006, 3.418, 1.464, 0.244, Iris-setosa
5.936, 2.77, 4.26, 1.326, Iris-versicolor

I know i need to use dictionaries and list comprehension. I also know i need to use the f.split(",") capability to add keys to the dictionaries where I can then add an then average them.

If anyone can help me with this code, thanks.

This is just some fiddling I did but I know I am very very far off. I pretty much only created the lists and dictionaries and know that the keys have to be appended still. Do i need to use both dictionary and list?

```
from __future__ import division, print_function

f = ('iris.txt', 'r')

f2 = ('iris-summary.txt', 'w')

for line in f
    c = f.split(',')

l_sl = []
l_sw = []
l_pl = []
l_pw = []
l_c = []

d_sepal_length = {}
d_sepal_width = {}
d_pedal_length = {}
d_pedal_width = {}
d_class = {}
```

Comment: update these lists *inside* the loop, then use [`sum`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum) and [`len`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum) to get averages.

Comment: can you show me an example for just the sepal length. from the looks of it I will just forego using dictionaries. i am not very comfortable with them anyways.

Answer (score 0):

```
k = [s.split(',') for s in open('iris.txt').readlines()]
sl = sum(s[0] for s in k)/len(k)
```

etc.

Comment: so how would i get it to output said data into the new file i created in f2

Comment: please do a little search. Python has an [*excellent* documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file-objects), to begin with.